# Providing json responses for react-native app with Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, rest, clean-architecture

I've been told that we have some limitations in front end side and we can't use the normal Eloquent json responses, instead I should prepare responses like:

```
[
    {
        "title": null,
        "type": "animals",
        "description": null,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "animal",
                "content": {
                    "id": 31,
                    "image": null,
                    "name": "Asghar's dog",
                    "age": null,
                    "race": null,
                    "species_id": 1,
                    "reason": [
                        "Home"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Recommend",
        "type": "recommendations",
        "description": null,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "self_checks",
                "content": {
                    "type": "prompt",
                    "title": "Self check for Asghar's dog.",
                    "description": "A short Self check.",
                    "cta_text": "Los geht’s"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "worm_checks",
                "content": {
                    "title": "Wurm-Vorsorge für Asghar's dog.",
                    "description": "Finde heraus, wie hoch das Wurm-Risiko deiner Fellnase ist.",
                    "cta_text": "Los geht’s",
                    "health_check_payload": {
                        "url": "https://****.de/check/worms?utm_term=Worms&utm_content=primer",
                        "title": "Wurm Check"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to know how should I structure my code to avoid code repetition and keep it clean. Also, I'm looking for any document regarding this type of responses.

Comment: So if I see the example, you don't want the data wrapper, correct?

Comment: @FendyHarianto No unfortunately the structure is way more complicated than data wrapping...

Comment: I can't see the complexity in it, it's should be just a data without a wrapper and a few relationship that can be done with a few resources file. Or maybe the example isn't complete?